# Think the logic is off? Trying to get the conditions to work as intended

Tags: powershell

Been working on a new script that will prompt a laptop user whether they need to reboot or not when they get Dell Updates.

The script is grabbing the return code no problem. But I think the logic in the conditions might be off? PS just ends up running the else statement:

```
# Determine if the laptop needs a reboot, if so prompt if not proceed 

$outputlog = Get-Content C:\Network\Dell-CU-apply.log | Select-String -pattern "Return Code:"
$returncode = $outputlog -replace '.*:',''
```

If the return code is 1, prompt reboot. If the return code is 0, terminate

```
if ($returncode -eq '1') {
Write-Host "Retreived a return code of 1, calling reboot script"
Start-Process "\\server\Installers\Workstations\Reboot Notice\RebootNotice w Hourly Notice Dell Updates.ps1" -Wait

}

else {
Write-Host "Retrieved a return code of 0, no reboot needed."

}
```

I tried changing the conditions but get the same result.

Comment: Return codes are usually numbers not strings. Remove the quotes - `'1'` is not the same as `1`

Comment: @MisterSmith `-replace` always outputs strings, `$returncode` would most certainly be a string or an array of strings in this scenario. And even if not, PowerShell's overloaded operators would still do the correct comparison :)

Comment: Can you show us some of that `C:\Network\Dell-CU-apply.log` file?

Comment: Fair point @mathias :-)  Actually I think you have a stray space in your `$returncode`. do `Write-Host "'$returncode'"` to see it. Maybe `$returncode = ($outputlog -replace '.*:','').Trim()` works for your data?